# Is possible knowing how long an user has been on a webpage by using PHP?

Tags: php

Is possible knowing how long an user has been on a webpage by using PHP? Or is possibe knowing the date and time he left?
I have a php code and I want to add an extra feature which shows me how long an user has been on a page or the date and time he left. I don't know if it's possible. I want do add it. Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');
$handle = fopen("log_1.txt", "a");
$rem_port = $_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT']; 
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

 function getClientIP(){       
     if (array_key_exists('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', $_SERVER)){
            return  $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];  
     }else if (array_key_exists('REMOTE_ADDR', $_SERVER)) { 
            return $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]; 
     }else if (array_key_exists('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', $_SERVER)) {
            return $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]; 
     } 

     return '';
}

function detectDevice(){
    $userAgent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
    $devicesTypes = array(
        "PC" => array("msie 10", "msie 9", "msie 8", "windows.*firefox", "windows.*chrome", "x11.*chrome", "x11.*firefox", "macintosh.*chrome", "macintosh.*firefox", "opera"),
        "Tablet"   => array("tablet", "android", "ipad", "tablet.*firefox"),
        "Mobile"   => array("mobile ", "android.*mobile", "iphone", "ipod", "opera mobi", "opera mini"),
        "bot"      => array("googlebot", "mediapartners-google", "adsbot-google", "duckduckbot", "msnbot", "bingbot", "ask", "facebook", "yahoo", "addthis")
    );
    foreach($devicesTypes as $deviceType => $devices) {           
        foreach($devices as $device) {
            if(preg_match("/" . $device . "/i", $userAgent)) {
                $deviceName = $deviceType;
            }
        }
    }
    return ucfirst($deviceName);
    }
 


function getOS() { 

    global $user_agent;

    $os_platform    =   "Unknown OS Platform";

    $os_array       =   array(
                            '/windows nt 10.0/i'    =>  'Windows 10',
                            '/windows nt 6.2/i'     =>  'Windows 8',
                            '/windows nt 6.1/i'     =>  'Windows 7',
                            '/windows nt 6.0/i'     =>  'Windows Vista',
                            '/windows nt 5.2/i'     =>  'Windows Server 2003/XP x64',
                            '/windows nt 5.1/i'     =>  'Windows XP',
                            '/windows xp/i'         =>  'Windows XP',
                            '/windows nt 5.0/i'     =>  'Windows 2000',
                            '/windows me/i'         =>  'Windows ME',
                            '/win98/i'              =>  'Windows 98',
                            '/win95/i'              =>  'Windows 95',
                            '/win16/i'              =>  'Windows 3.11',
                            '/macintosh|mac os x/i' =>  'Mac OS X',
                            '/mac_powerpc/i'        =>  'Mac OS 9',
                            '/linux/i'              =>  'Linux',
                            '/ubuntu/i'             =>  'Ubuntu',
                            '/iphone/i'             =>  'iPhone',
                            '/ipod/i'               =>  'iPod',
                            '/ipad/i'               =>  'iPad',
                            '/android/i'            =>  'Android',
                            '/blackberry/i'         =>  'BlackBerry',
                            '/webos/i'              =>  'Mobile'
                        );

    foreach ($os_array as $regex => $value) { 

        if (preg_match($regex, $user_agent)) {
            $os_platform    =   $value;
        }

    }   

    return $os_platform;

}

function getBrowser() {

    global $user_agent;

    $browser        =   "Unknown Browser";

    $browser_array  =   array(
                            '/msie/i'       =>  'Internet Explorer',
                            '/firefox/i'    =>  'Firefox',
                            '/safari/i'     =>  'Safari',
                            '/chrome/i'     =>  'Chrome',
                            '/OPR/i'        =>  'Opera',
                            '/netscape/i'   =>  'Netscape',
                            '/maxthon/i'    =>  'Maxthon',
                            '/konqueror/i'  =>  'Konqueror',
                            '/mobile/i'     =>  'Handheld Browser'
                        );

    foreach ($browser_array as $regex => $value) { 

        if (preg_match($regex, $user_agent)) {
            $browser    =   $value;
        }

    }

    return $browser;

}

$realip         =   getClientIP();
$user_os        =   getOS();
$user_browser   =   getBrowser();
$detect_device  =   detectDevice();

$device_details = "IP: ".$realip."\r\nPort: ".$rem_port."\r\nUserAgent: ".$user_agent."\r\nBrowser: ".$user_browser."\r\nOperative System: ".$user_os."\r\nDevice Type: ".$detect_device."\r\nHost: ".gethostbyaddr($realip)."\r\nDate: ".$date."\r\n";

fwrite($handle,$device_details);
fclose($handle);
header ('Location: /1.txt');

?>
```

Comment: Not using PHP alone. PHP doesnt execute on exit. You could use `beforeunload` with JS to execute an ajax event. That wont always work though (e.g. js disabled etc)

Comment: you can measure the time between 2 requests, if you know the user (aka, after a login)

Comment: No. Instead of a classical desktop application, which would run in a circle, a PHP program is more a straight line. It starts, makes its work and then ends, usually all of that is done in a few milliseconds. You would need JavaScript for that.

Comment: Thanks for answering. How can I edit my code in order to add a javascript code? Where will I get such information? Thanks again